# OpenCL floor function doesn't return correct number

Tags: c, floating-point, opencl

I am trying to convert a CUDA code snippet in OpenCL.

###### CUDA code:

```
# Variable point is CUDA float4.
# X_MIN_RANGE, Y_MIN_RANGE, PILLAR_SIZE and GRID_X_SIZE are all defined as
# constants in a header file.

int idx = floorf((point.x - X_MIN_RANGE)/PILLAR_SIZE);
int idy = floorf((point.y - Y_MIN_RANGE)/PILLAR_SIZE);
unsigned int index = idy * GRID_X_SIZE + idx;
```

###### OpenCL code:

```
# Variable point_coord is OpenCL float4.
# X_MIN_RANGE, Y_MIN_RANGE, PILLAR_SIZE and GRID_X_SIZE are defined as constants using #define.

#define X_MIN_RANGE 0.0
#define Y_MIN_RANGE -39.68
#define PILLAR_SIZE 0.16
#define GRID_X_SIZE 432

/*... Some code here...*/

int idx = floor((point.x - X_MIN_RANGE) / PILLAR_SIZE);
int idy = floor((point.y - Y_MIN_RANGE) / PILLAR_SIZE);
unsigned int index = idy * GRID_X_SIZE + idx;
```

I have some issues with the results of floor. For instance, for a point of coordinates {12.48, -10.629, -0.223, 0.4}, X_MIN_RANGE = 0.0, Y_MIN_RANGE = -39.68, PILLAR_SIZE = 0.16 and GRID_X_SIZE = 432 I'm expecting to see:

*idx = floor((12.48 - 0.0) / 0.16) = floor(78.0) = 78*
*idy = floor((-10.69 + 39.68) / 0.16) = floor(181.1875) = 181*

*index = 181 * 432 + 78 = 78270*

For the CUDA code, I am getting the correct result, however for the OpenCL code I am getting  78269 for the same coordinates as the floor operation for idx returns 77 instead of 77. I had a look for similar examples and it always happens when the decimal part of the argument in floor is 0, so I assume that the result falls on the wrong side of the integer.

As this part of the code needs to be quite accurate, do you know how can I make sure floor rounds integers correctly? I have alredy tried to rearrange the operations and to use double instead of float, but that didn't help.

Comment: Are you sure that the result, that you pass to `floorf`, is `78.0` and not `77.99999999...`? Can you add the exact `#define`s for all the numbers?

Comment: There's such thing as numerical errors. If the correct answer is 78.0 then it can easily be 77.99999. If you apply `floor` then it is the expected result. Did you mean to use `round` instead of `floor`?

Comment: I am pretty sure that's the case, If I write the argument to output I'm getting 78.0 but I'm pretty sure it's due to formatting. In that case, i tried to swap the division with the multiplication as in OpenCL float multiplication is supposed to have 0 ULP, but I'm getting the same result.

Comment: I want to use floor as I need to round the float to closest smallest integer, not round.

Answer (score 2):

`(point.x - X_MIN_RANGE)/PILLAR_SIZE` is calculated as `double`, because all defines are `double`. So the result is a `double`.

If you then use `floorf` (the f at the end stands for `float`), it will be casted to a `float` before the function call. If you use `floor`, it stays a `double`.

The `float` value is indeed `78.00000` exact, so `floorf` returns `78`.

The `double` is `77.99999713897705078125` and then `floor` returns `77`.

You can fix that by either using `float` for the calculation or cast the result before the function call. You could also add a very small number, like `0.0001` before the `floor` to remove floating point inexactness.

Comment: Casting (point.x - X_MIN_RANGE)/PILLAR_SIZE to float then adding 0.0001 did the job for all the wrong results I was getting. Thanks!